# How do I fix the error "✘ Invalid config override '-': name should start with --" when using SpaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am currently trying to create an intent classifier for a chatbot project I have to do for school. I'm trying to follow the tutorial found here titled "Chatbot Intent Classification Example" https://www.width.ai/post/spacy-text-classification.

When trying to run the convert script, I get the following error:

```
> py -m spacy project run convert
✘ Invalid config override '-': name should start with --
```

I have altered the code as they do in the tutorial, however, when I reverted it to the original, I still got the same error. I have never used SpaCy before so I am completely lost. How can I fix this?

Here is the project I cloned as instructed from the tutorial: https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/pipelines/textcat_demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to change directory name to remove a hyphen.